Modify Preview app behavior when called from the command line?
I frequently want to open, view and compare a small number of pdf images - e.g., 9 graphs, each in its own file. I am a command-line user, not a mouse and click guy. Preview does a great job of rendering images, so I'd like to stick with that. Here are the options I can think of; am I missing something?

Open them all in preview (e.g. open *.pdf), click on each window in turn, type "cmd+-" multiple times to shrink the figure, then use "option+green dot in title bar" to resize (shrink) the window itself.  That's what I do now; very slow and awkward.

Similar to #1 but just shrink the window (no cmd+-). Fewer steps than 1a but making all the windows the same size ends up taking just as long or longer.

Open all the files as tabs in a single window, shrink the window. Then either flip through tabs or pull out the tabs into separate windows. Worked great but preview no longer allows this -pdfs are opened in separate windows even with  Settings/Images/"open all files in one window" selected

Pass an option to preview.app using open --args. This does not work because preview.app does not accept options.

Write an applescript to handle this -- would work, but I find applescript to be very cumbersome for tasks like this.

Use a commandline tool to merge the pdfs together into a single pdf, open the merged file, shrink it once, and view each figure as a page in the pdf. Can switch to view/contact sheet to see them simultaneously. Not bad, but not quite as good as individual windows or tabs.

Use a different pdf viewer, like ghostscript, that is more command-line friendly. Would work, but preview does a really nice job of displaying images so I'd prefer sticking with it.


Any other options?  Thanks!

As you say: there are no command line options for Preview. You'll either have to use AppleScript (or its JavaScript equivalent); or use a different app. I'm not convinced that Preview displays images any better than any other app. It also has a lot of quirks and problems/bugs.

Are these graphs already PDFs,  or do you also have access to them in an image format?

@nohillside -- I really like vector graphics, so I generate these as either postscript or pdfs. In a publication, for example, I want readers to be able to zoom in without pixelation.

@benwiggy -- any specific recommendations?

Well, if you could create the graphs, at least for the review, as png or svg, you could pit them with into a HTML table and look at them locally in Safari.
